# Apache Axis NoClassDefFoundError when trying to list services

Tags: web-services, tomcat, axis, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting an exception being thrown when I try and list my Axis-powered web services, when I try and access the WSDL for any service and when I try and use the service in question:

> Servlet.service() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.MyAwesomeServiceSoapBindingImpl

Now, I know that class is available in a jar in the Axis web service's WEB-INF/lib directory, and I have reloaded Axis since I put it there.

Any ideas, anyone?

[tomcat 5.5.x, Apache Axis version: 1.4 Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object that MyAwesomeServiceSoapBindingImpl wraps isn't instantiating property.

I'm guessing that underlying problem is masked by this (apparently totally unrelated at first glance) type of problem because of the way Axis initialises its services...

Once I fixed the underlying problem everything kicked back into life.